# Use recursive parent child query traitement instead of java traitement

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot

Usng java I can make a recursive tree parent child .

But  usint this java traitement it consumes too much process and memory.
I want to simplify this method using a recursive postgres method and use the result in the java method.

I work with Spring boot version 2 and I use JPA and hibernate version 5.2

the @RestController class

```
 @GetMapping("/collegeBook")
    @Timed
    public ResponseEntity<List<CollegeDTO>> getAllCollegeBook(Pageable pageable, @RequestParam(name="lang", required=false) String lang) {

        Page<CollegeDTO> page = collegeService.findAllCollege(pageable, lang);
        HttpHeaders headers = PaginationUtil.generatePaginationHttpHeaders(page, "/api/collegeBook");
        return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).body(page.getContent());
    }
```

and this is the method in service class

```
 public Page<CollegeDTO> findAllCollege(Pageable pageable, String lang) {

      List<CollegeDTO> list=collegeRepository.findCollegeList(pageable, lang);
      List<CollegeDTO> unitChildList=getChildrenList(list,lang,pageable);

      return new PageImpl<CollegeDTO>(unitChildList);
  }





  private List<CollegeDTO> getChildrenList(
        List<CollegeDTO> collegeList, String lang,Pageable pageable) {

     for(CollegeDTO collegeDTO : collegeList) {

         List<CollegeDTO> childrenListEntity = collegeRepository.findCollegeByParentId(pageable, lang,CollegeDTO.getValue());
         collegeDTO.setChildren(getChildrenList(childrenListEntity,lang,pageable));

       }

          return collegeList;
      }
```

this is the Repository method

```
public List<CollegeDTO> findCollegeList(Pageable pageable, String lang) {

    String querystr = "SELECT ";

    querystr += " collegelang.name AS text ,";
    querystr += " college.id AS value ,";
    querystr += " (select count(*) from student where student.college_id = college.id) as nbr ";
    querystr += " FROM college college ";
    querystr += " LEFT OUTER JOIN collegelang collegel ON collegelang.college_id = college.id ";
    querystr += " Where collegelang.lang = :lang and college.status ='1' and parentid is null order by app_order asc";

    log.debug("-- Query:" + querystr);

    Query query = em.createNativeQuery(querystr, "CollegeDTOMap");
    query.setParameter("lang", lang);

    List<CollegeDTO> collegeDTOs = query.getResultList();

    return collegeDTOs;
  }



  public List<CollegeDTO> findCollegeByParentId(Pageable pageable, String lang, String idParent) {

     String querystr = "SELECT ";

    querystr += " collegelang.name AS text ,";
    querystr += " college.id AS value ,";
    querystr += " (select count(*) from student where student.college_id = college.id) as nbr";
    querystr += " FROM college college ";
    querystr += " LEFT OUTER JOIN collegelang collegelang ON collegelang.college_id = college.id ";
    querystr += " Where collegelang.lang = :lang and college.status ='1' and un.parentid = :idParent ";


    log.debug("-- Query:" + querystr);

    Query query = em.createNativeQuery(querystr, "CollegeDTOMap");
    query.setParameter("lang", lang);
    query.setParameter("idParent", idParent);
    List<CollegeDTO> collegeDTOs = query.getResultList();

    return collegeDTOs;
  }
```

CollegeDTO class

```
 public class CollegeDTO{

  private String text;
  private String value;
  private String nbr;
  private List<CollegeDTO> children;

  public CollegeDTO(String text,String value,String nbr, List<CollegeDTO> children) {
    super();
    this.text = text;
    this.value = value;
    this.nbr = nbr;
    this.children = children;
  }
//getter and setter .......
  }
```

College class

```
 @SqlResultSetMapping(
            name = "CollegeDTOMap",
            classes = @ConstructorResult(
              targetClass = CollegeDTO.class,
              columns = {
                @ColumnResult(name = "text"),
                @ColumnResult(name = "value"),
                @ColumnResult(name = "nbr")
              }
            )
          )
  public class College {

  ..............
  ..............
  }
```

**Updated :**

I try with this query but I didn't find the way to use the result in java traitement .

My goals is to return `Page<CollegeDTO>`

which contain **child having CollegeDTO** as a type

```
with recursive nodes as    (
 select college.id AS value, CAST(collegelang.name  AS varchar) AS text,
 (select count(*) from student where student.college_id = college.id) as nbr,
 ARRAY[college.id,collegelang.name,(select count(*) from student where student.college_id = college.id)]
 as parents,college.app_order

 FROM college college 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN collegelang collegelang ON collegelang.college_id = college.id
 Where collegelang.lang = 'AR' and college.status ='1' and parentid is null 



 union all  

 select o.id AS value, CAST(collegelang.name  AS varchar)   AS text,(select count(*) from student where student.college_id = college.id) as nbr 
 ,parents || ARRAY[o.id,collegelang.name,(select count(*) from student where student.college_id = college.id)] 
 ,o.app_order  

 FROM college o  
  join nodes n on n.value = o.parentid  
  LEFT OUTER JOIN collegelang collegelang ON collegelang.unit_id = o.id and collegelang.lang='AR'
  where o.status ='1'



 )  
 select  CAST(text  AS varchar) as text,value as value,nbr as nbr, parents as children from nodes  
 order by app_order asc
```

I try to modify College class

```
 @SqlResultSetMapping(
            name = "CollegeDTOMap",
            classes = @ConstructorResult(
              targetClass = CollegeDTO.class,
              columns = {
                @ColumnResult(name = "text"),
                @ColumnResult(name = "value"),
                @ColumnResult(name = "nbr"),
                @ColumnResult(name = "children")     // add this line
              }
            )
          )
  public class College {

  ..............
  ..............
  }
```

but I have this error using the previous query

```
  Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not resolve column name in result set [children]
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 2003
```

Comment: You should try to simplify your question. Its not really clear what problem you have.

Comment: I have updated my question . my goals is to return from one recursive query the list of College and her children

Comment: You may consider using FluentJPA's support for [recursive CTE](https://github.com/streamx-co/FluentJPA/wiki/Common-Table-Expressions).